# How to install Selenium2Library for Robot Framework using pip + Jython?

Tags: selenium-webdriver, pip, jython, robotframework, jython-2.7

Since version 2.7.0 Jython contains pip bundled in. It just needs to be activated by running the following command before using it:

```
jython -m ensurepip
```

So actually after that it should be possible to install Selenium2Library for Robot Framework with

```
jython -m pip install robotframework-selenium2library
```

right?

But when I do this I get the following error:

```
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'geteuid'
```

Here is the full cmd / shell output:

```
C:\foldername>jython -m pip install selenium2library
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Jython27\Lib\runpy.py", line 151, in _run_module_as_main
    mod_name, loader, code, fname = _get_module_details(mod_name)
  File "C:\Jython27\Lib\runpy.py", line 151, in _run_module_as_main
    mod_name, loader, code, fname = _get_module_details(mod_name)
  File "C:\Jython27\Lib\runpy.py", line 109, in _get_module_details
    return _get_module_details(pkg_main_name)
  File "C:\Jython27\Lib\runpy.py", line 109, in _get_module_details
    return _get_module_details(pkg_main_name)
  File "C:\Jython27\Lib\runpy.py", line 101, in _get_module_details
    loader = get_loader(mod_name)
  File "C:\Jython27\Lib\pkgutil.py", line 478, in get_loader
    return find_loader(fullname)
  File "C:\Jython27\Lib\pkgutil.py", line 488, in find_loader
    for importer in iter_importers(fullname):
  File "C:\Jython27\Lib\pkgutil.py", line 439, in iter_importers
    __import__(pkg)
  File "C:\Jython27\Lib\site-packages\pip\__init__.py", line 10, in <module>
    from pip.util import get_installed_distributions, get_prog
  File "C:\Jython27\Lib\site-packages\pip\util.py", line 17, in <module>
    from pip.locations import (
  File "C:\Jython27\Lib\site-packages\pip\locations.py", line 109, in <module>
    build_prefix = _get_build_prefix()
  File "C:\Jython27\Lib\site-packages\pip\locations.py", line 90, in _get_build_
prefix
    if file_uid != os.geteuid():
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'geteuid'
```

Why am I getting this error?

BTW: installing from source works nice with

```
jython setup.py install
```

Addition information: I´m on Windows 8.1 64 bit with Java 1.8, Jython 2.7.0, Robot Framework 2.8.7

Comment: Further details on this matter: https://github.com/rtomac/robotframework-selenium2library/issues/409#issuecomment-109435762

Comment: also: http://bugs.jython.org/issue2345

Comment: @JavierJ - Thank you, It made it on a Windows 8.1 machine but still have some troubles on a Windows 7 machine at work. Another possibility is may be installing pip manually with the help of [get-pip.py](https://pip.pypa.io/en/latest/installing/) (download it [here](https://pip.pypa.io/en/latest/installing/)) and then calling `jython get-pip.py` in download folder.

Answer (score 3):

I ran into this too after installing Jython 2.7.0. It seems that for some reason PIP 1.6 (really old) was being used (which leads to that error), this steps should fix it:

1. Delete the folder %TEMP%\pip_build_[username]
2. Run `jython -m pip install -U pip to upgrade pip` to uninstall and upgrade PIP to 7.x

Hope this helps!